# Exportar datos a excel desde view laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel, maatwebsite

Hola he estado intentando exportar desde un view usando `laravel-excel maatwebsite`, un registro que muestro en una tabla pero la verdad no comprendo muy bien que es lo que debo hacer, ya que al tratar de exportar me aparece el siguiente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En todos los ejemplos que he investigado veo que usan el ::all() en el Export pero ahi trae todos los registro y yo solo necesito un registro.

Aqui adjunto mi estructura:

**GasolinaExport.php**

```
<?php  
namespace App\Exports;
use App\Models\Gas;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView

class GasolinaExport implements FromView{
protected $view;
protected $data;

    public function __construct($view, $gas){
        $this->view = $view;
        $this->gas = $gas;
    }
    public function view(): View{
        return view($this->view,
         $this->gas);
    }
}
```

**export.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.plantilla')
@section('title', 'Gasolina')
@section('content')
<div class="p-5 rounded">
    <h1>Exportacion</h1>
    <p class="lead">Use el menu superior para entrar en las opciones que desea.</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <caption>Informe de Combustible {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($gas->fecha)->format('d/m/Y')}}</caption>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>95</th>
        <th>91</th>
        <th>Diesel</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Efectivo</th>
        <td>{{$gas->efectivo_95}}</td>
        <td>{{$gas->efectivo_91}}</td>
        <td>{{$gas->diesel_efectivo}}</td>
        <td>{{($gas->efectivo_95 + $gas->efectivo_91 + $gas->diesel_efectivo)}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Cheque</th>
        <td>{{$gas->cheque_95}}</td>
        <td>{{$gas->cheque_91}}</td>
        <td>{{$gas->diesel_cheque}}</td>
        <td>{{($gas->cheque_95 + $gas->cheque_91 + $gas->diesel_cheque)}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Tarjeta</th>
        <td>{{$gas->tarjeta_95}}</td>
        <td>{{$gas->tarjeta_91}}</td>
        <td>{{$gas->diesel_tarjeta}}</td>
        <td>{{($gas->tarjeta_95 + $gas->tarjeta_91 + $gas->diesel_tarjeta)}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
@endsection
```

**GasolinaController.php**

```
public function export(Gas $gasolina) 
{
return Excel::download(new GasolinaExport('gasolina.export', $gasolina), 'gas.xlsx');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema esta en como llamas a la **vista** o mejor dicho, como le pasas los datos, estas pasandole al **método** `view()`, dos parametros, pero uno de esos parámetros debería ser:

1. El nombre de la vista `String`
2. Los datos a pasarle a la vista `Array`

debería ser algo así:

```php
<?php  
namespace App\Exports;
use App\Models\Gas;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;

class GasolinaExport implements FromView
{
  protected $view;
  protected $gas;

    public function __construct($view, $gas)
    {
        $this->view = $view;
        $this->gas = $gas;
    }
    public function view(): View
    {
        return view($this->view, 
        [
          'gas' => $this->gas
        ]);
    }
}
```

Debes pasar en ese `Array` los datos en conjunto *Clave/Valor* en forma de **array asociativo**

##### Nota:

1. También veo que te falto un punto y coma `;` aquí `use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView`
2. La propiedad `$gas` en tu clase `GasolinaExport` no existe, debes cambiar `$data` por `$gas`:

```php
// Lo tienes así
  protected $view;
  protected $data;
```

```php
// Debe ser así
  protected $view;
  protected $gas;
```